# Rotating a circle about a larger circle

Tags: animation, geometry

I've got some wonderful answers this morning on Mathematica Stack Exchange. See [Diagonals of a regular octagon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95528/diagonals-of-a-regular-octagon) and [Determine the height of a box packed with spheres](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95566/determine-height-of-box-packed-with-spheres). I'm just smiling with the amount I am learning with these responses, so I'd like to ask one more question.

The diagram below shows the circular face of a clock with radius 20 cm and a circular disk with radius 10 cm externally tangent to the clock face at 12 o’clock. The disk has an arrow painted on it, initially pointing in the upward vertical direction. Let the disk roll clockwise around the clock face. At what point on the clock face will the disk be tangent when the arrow is next pointing in the upward vertical direction?

[image]

How can I use *Mathematica* to animate the smaller circle with the arrow rotating about the large circle to show students the answer?

**My adaption from the [Plotting the Epicycloid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32444/plotting-an-epicycloid)**

```
R = 20; r = 10;
fy[\[Theta]_, a_: 1] := (R + r) Cos[\[Theta]] + 
   a r Cos[(R + r) \[Theta]/r];
fx[\[Theta]_, a_: 1] := (R + r) Sin[\[Theta]] + 
   a r Sin[(R + r) \[Theta]/r];

plot[max_] := 
 ParametricPlot[{fx[\[Theta]], fy[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, max},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
  Epilog -> {
    Thick,
    Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, R],
    Black, Circle[{fx[max, 0], fy[max, 0]}, r],
    Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{fx[max], fy[max]}],
    Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{fx[max, -1], fy[max, -1]}],
    Black, Line[{{fx[max, 0], fy[max, 0]}, {fx[max], fy[max]}}]
    },
  PlotRange -> 40]

Manipulate[
 plot[max], {max, 0.000001, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Looks like the answer is 4 pm. Sorry about the image, as the number in the entry box should show $2\pi/3$, but it is blocked because of size after I typed it in.

Also, that is what the solution is as posted at [The Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2015_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_14).

Comment: Look up [Epicycloid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Epicycloid/) and related demonstrations.

Comment: Look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32444/plotting-an-epicycloid) Mathematica.SE Q&A.

Comment: On the face of it, this seems a relatively straightforward task.  Are you asking only that somebody do it for you?  Or are you running into a more specific problem?

Comment: @Pickett Isn't it close enough to be a duplicate?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sure, done.

Comment: Everyone, thanks for pointing me to the page [Plotting an epicycloid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32444/plotting-an-epicycloid). I am getting a tremendous amount of help today. Thanks.

Comment: I am feeling very frustrated right now. I was within 30 secs of posting what I think is a very nice answer for this question when it was closed. I don't think its a duplicate. David doesn't want to draw a epicycloid and there no reference to such in my answer, which only involves drawing circles and arrows. I request that this question be re-opened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun:

Setup:

```
clock = Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2], 
    Table[{Text[ Mod[3 - 6 j/Pi, 12, 1], 1.65 {Cos[j], Sin[j]}], 
      Line[# {Cos[j], Sin[j]} & /@ {1.8, 2}]}, {j, 0, 23 Pi/12, 
      Pi/6}], PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0}]}];
epi[t_] := 3 {Sin[t], Cos[t]} + {Sin[3 t], Cos[3 t]}
```

Visualization:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[epi[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[epi[j]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashed], clock, 
  Graphics[{Circle[3 {Sin[j], Cos[j]}, 1], 
    Text[Rotate[Style["\[DoubleUpArrow]", 40], -3 j], 
     3 {Sin[j], Cos[j]}]}], Axes -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}], {j, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely wonderful! What fun! I will definitely share this with all our participants at our activity. It so clearly shows the solution. Thanks. :-)

Comment: For reference: the specific epicycloid being traced here is called a *nephroid*.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are right, there is a mistake in the reasoning of my now deleted answer. However, I thought some the cosmetic code I wrote for the failed answer might still be of interest to you, so I integrated your code with the cosmetic elements of mine.

```
R = 20; r = 10;
fy[θ_, a_: 1] := (R + r) Cos[θ] + a r Cos[(R + r) θ/r];
fx[θ_, a_: 1] := (R + r) Sin[θ] + a r Sin[(R + r) θ/r];

origin = {0, 0};
center = {PointSize[Large], Point[origin]};
scale = Range[12];
scalePts = R {Sin @ #, Cos @ #}& /@ N[(30 scale) °];
ticks = Line @ ({#, .9 #}& /@ scalePts); 
lbls = Thread[Text[Style[#, 14]& /@ scale, .8 scalePts]];

plot[max_] :=
  ParametricPlot[{fx[θ], fy[θ]}, {θ, 0, max},
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
    Axes -> False,
    PlotRange -> 40]

Manipulate[
  Block[{θ = max °},
    Show[
      If[θ > 0., plot[θ ], Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 40]], 
      Graphics[{
        Thick, Blue, Circle[origin, R],
        Black, center, lbls, ticks, Circle[{fx[θ, 0], fy[θ, 0]}, r],
        Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{fx[θ], fy[θ]}],
        Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{fx[θ, -1], fy[θ, -1]}], 
        Black, Line[{{fx[θ, 0], fy[θ, 0]}, {fx[θ], fy[θ]}}]}],
      PlotRangePadding -> 2]],
  {max, 0., 360., 5., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

With these changes, your demonstration will look like this

[image: demo]

which is more in line with the top image of your question. I hope you find some use for this in your classroom.

Comment: Well it is an epicycloid after all -- what did you mean? Just that you didn't use the word?  It still seems a duplicate to me, and David's code you use even comes from Pickett's answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

#### Major edit

Yes, it is possible to save the phenomena and work only with rotating circles, eschewing any reference to epicycles. (Of course, they are still there.)

I will do it in two steps.

1. A helper function that will generate the graphics primitives for the rolling circle.

   ```
   roller[r1_, r2_, angle_] :=
     Module[{r3 = r1 + r2, center},
       center = r3 {Sin @ angle, Cos @ angle};
       {Circle[center, r2],
        Rotate[Arrow[{center - {0, r2}, center + {0, r2}}, .2], -angle r3/r2]}]
   ```

   Note that the only change from my previously posted, wrong version is to substitute `r3` for `r1`. `roller` will work for cicles of any radius, `r1 > r2`
2. An `Manipulate` expression that draws the larger circle in the background and uses the helper to rotate the smaller circle.

   ```
   Manipulate[
     With[{r1 = 2., r2 = 1.},
     Module[{origin, halfW, center, scale, scalePts, ticks, lbls},
     origin = {0, 0};
     halfW = r1 + 2 r2;
     center = {PointSize[Large], Point[origin]};
     scale = Range[12];
     scalePts = r1 {Sin @ #, Cos @ #} & /@ N[(30 scale) °];
     ticks = Line @ ({#, .925 # } & /@ scalePts);
     lbls = Thread[Text[Style[#, 14] & /@ scale, .8 scalePts]];
     Graphics[{roller[r1, r2, θ °]},
       PlotRange -> {{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &[halfW], 
       Prolog -> {Circle[origin, r1], center, lbls, ticks}]]],
    {θ, 0., 360., 5., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    SaveDefinitions -> True]
   ```

The above code produces a demonstration that looks like this as it hits the four o'clock point.

[image: roller]

Comment: Wonderful! I want to thank you for your effort.